# How to capture the status change of a process in selenium, after the process is kickstarted(Run)

Tags: selenium

In my UI, there are status changes likw, once I click on "run".. the status changes liek this .."Initialised" ...."Scheduled"..."started" ...."InProgress"..."Passed"/"Failed", How can i capture the status of this dynamically and get the complete stream of status and show to the user like this "Initialized-->Scheduled-->Started-->INprogres-->Passed".

Any refrence links or suggustions please.

The status happens in same element. BUt there is not specific time it takes from one status change to another.

```
try{
String strRunstatus = TestExecutionStatus.get(1).getText();
String statusTraverse = null;
if(statusTraverse = null)
statusTraverse 
while(true)
waitMilliSec(2000);
{
if(strRunStatus.equals("Not Started"))
{
statusTraverse = statusTraverse+ "--> " +strRunStatus;
continue;
}
if(strRunStatus.equals("Started"))
{
statusTraverse = statusTraverse+ "--> " +strRunStatus;
continue;
}
if(strRunStatus.equals("Passed"))
{
statusTraverse = statusTraverse+ "--> " +strRunStatus;
break;
}
if(strRunStatus.equals("Failed"))
{
statusTraverse = statusTraverse+ "--> " +strRunStatus;
break;
}
}
```

Exception : No elemnt exception

Comment: Post your relevant Html and error code trials please?

Comment: ```<tr class="ng-scope">
 <td class="ng-binding">TESTCASE1></td>
<td class="ng-binding"</td>
<td>
<span class="lable label-default" ng-bind="scan.scanStatus">Not Started</span>
</td>

Comment: @KunduK , When the status changes, it changes in the same span class.

Comment: Need few more mins, i will have to write the code fseeing from VPN.

Comment: @KunduK, please find the code above

Comment: @kunduk, could you please chekc this, i this issue is happening because of the alert. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61206486/capture-the-alert-message-text-which-is-displayed-in-a-textbox-and-in-editable

Comment: I will come back sometimes later.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept is correct you need infinite loop the check however You can check the length count of the elements and then goes into if block and get the status.

```
while(true)
waitMilliSec(2000);
{
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='scan.scanStatus' and text()='Not Started']")).size()>0)
{
  System.out.println("Status : " + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='scan.scanStatus' and text()='Not Started']")).getText());
  continue;
}
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='scan.scanStatus' and text()='Started']")).size()>0)
{
  System.out.println("Status : " + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='scan.scanStatus' and text()='Started']")).getText());
  continue;
}
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='scan.scanStatus' and text()='Passed']")).size()>0)
{
  System.out.println("Status : " + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='scan.scanStatus' and text()='Passed']")).getText());
  break;
}
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='scan.scanStatus' and text()='Failed']")).size()>0)
{
  System.out.println("Status : " + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='scan.scanStatus' and text()='Failed']")).getText());
  break;
}
}
```